Quarkus Smallrye Eclipse Microprofile OpenAPI schema
So I am currently trying to update my backend which is running Quarkus to version 3.
The new version of Quarkus is using smallrye, but I am having some trouble with generating my OpenAPI specification files (.yaml) as it is not generating the enum property as expected.
I am currently using the smallrye-open-api-maven-plugin version 3.11.
The code below is code I made up, but is based on the experience in my code base.
I have the following Java class:
import org.eclipse.microprofile.openapi.annotations.media.Schema;
@Schema(title = "CoolStuff", description = "This is actually the cool stuff")
public class CoolClass {
   public enum CoolEnum {
      Cool,
      NotCool;
   }

   @Schema(description = "The command")
   private final CoolEnum command;
   @Schema(description = "The id")
   private final String id;

   public CoolClass(CoolEnum command, String id) {
      this.command = command;
      this.id = id;
   }

   public CoolEnum getCommand() {
      return command;
   }
   public String getId() {
      return id;
   }
}

When compiling and making the maven plugin generate the .yaml file I get this:
CoolClass:
   title: CoolStuff
   description: This is actually the cool stuff
   type: object
   properties:
      command:
         description: The command
         type: object
      id:
         description: The id
         type string

I would have expected the following .yaml, which is the .yaml I need:
CoolClass:
   title: CoolStuff
   description: This is actually the cool stuff
   type: object
   properties:
      command:
         description: The command
         type: string
         enum:
            - Cool
            - NotCool
      id:
         description: The id
         type string

I do not really see what I have done wrong here?
I have another example as well:
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import org.eclipse.microprofile.openapi.annotations.enums.SchemaType;
@Schema(title = "CoolStuffCool", description = "This is actually the cool stuff")
public class CoolClassClass {
   public enum CoolEnumEnum {
      Cool,
      NotCool;
   }
   public enum NotCoolEnumEnum {
      Work,
      NotWork;
   }

   @Schema(description = "The command", implementation = CoolEnumEnum.class, type = SchemaType.STRING)
   private final CoolEnumEnum command;
   @Schema(description = "The mode", implementation = NotCoolEnumEnum.class, type = SchemaType.STRING)
   private final NotCoolEnumEnum mode;

   public CoolClassClass(CoolEnumEnum command, NotCoolEnumEnum mode) {
      this.command = command;
      this.mode = mode;
   }

   public CoolEnumEnum getCommand() {
      return command;
   }
   public NotCoolEnumEnum getMode() {
      return mode;
   }
   
   @JsonCreator
   public static CoolClassClass firValue(
      @JsonProperty("command") String command, @JsonProperty("mode") String mode) {
      CoolEnumEnum commandValue = (value != null && !value.isEmpty()) ? CoolEnumEnum.valueOf(command)) : null;
      NotCoolEnumEnum modeValue = (value != null && !value.isEmpty()) ? NotCoolEnumEnum.valueOf(mode)) : null;
   return new CoolClassClass(command, mode);
  }
}

The class CoolClassClass is being generated correctly with the enum properties. I have tried adding the @JsonCreator to the CoolClass but that did not work. I also tried adding the implementation and type in the CoolClass but also without luck.
When expressing the enumeration property with the values manually, then the .yaml is also generated correctly, however I am relying heavy on that the enum properties can be generated automatically from the code, as the general backend is dependent on multiple classes, which needs to update the APIs for the other classes.
Is there something I am missing?
